# Do I need a transit visa (Amsterdam to Delhi via London)?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, transit-visas, lhr

I am taking a flight from Amsterdam to Delhi via London Heathrow Airport. I have a British Airways flight to London and a Virgin Atlantic flight from London to Delhi. The customer care on British Airways has confirmed that I can do a through check-in, meaning I don't have to collect my baggage at London and check it in again. I have a layover of about 6 hours in London, and the next flight is on the same calendar day. I am an Indian national.

Can anyone who has been through the same situation clarify if I would need a transit visa for London? Also, I don't hold any other visas right now (USA, Australia etc). I am traveling to Europe on a tourist (type C) visa, and this is my flight back to India. Drop a comment if you'd need additional information!

According to the UK website, I would need a transit visa, but is there any possibility that **people have traveled along the same route** and it wouldn't be required if I'm not leaving the airport? My flights are non-refundable and Virgin Atlantic has declined to refund any partial amount as well.

Comment: According to U.K.gov you need a https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But there are multiple answers on the exact same question on Quora where many travelers did not have a transit visa and got away with it. I wanted to know if any traveler was able to transit through london meeting the actual requirements before I cancel my flight.

Comment: @Traveller Are you sure that OP needs the transit visa? AFAIK, you don't need a transit visa if your onward flight leaves on the same calendar day to when you arrive and your baggage is transferred by the airline.

Comment: So I checked the website. You do need a transit visa as @Traveller mentioned. I didn't notice that you don't hold a residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA)

Comment: @ArpitBajpai it's rather absurd that the UK waives the transit visa requirement for those with visitor visas from non-EU countries such as the US and New Zealand but not for those with type-C Schengen visas, but it is nonetheless true. Anuj Menta: perhaps those who succeeded had a qualifying document.  It seems that you do not, however.

Comment: @Traveller Indeed, It does not make sense ask for a DATV for short layovers considering the number of passengers travel from the EU through Heathrow while waiving it off for the other non-EU countries.

Comment: @Arpit Bajpal Well, the approach seems consistent with the UK not being part of Schengen.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You've looked at the official UK requirements and they say you need a visa. That completely answers your question. You've also found some people on internet forums giving the unofficial advice that you don't need a visa. You don't entirely believe that, so you've gone to a different internet forum to ask for more unofficial advice. What could we possibly say that would be more convincing than the official UK Government advice?

Comment: @phoog Yes. That is the only thing I am not sure about.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was hoping this question would reach someone who did not notice this and reached Amsterdam without a transit visa with the above conditions. Let us say they allowed him to pass through, I can risk not booking another flight and not waste money. Desperate times call for desperate measures :(

Comment: @Traveller the UK is also not part of the US, New Zealand, etc., yet it accepts their visitor visas as sufficient to waive the DATV requirement.  Why not Schengen visitor visas?

Comment: @ArpitBajpai be careful of confusing "waive" and "wave off."  Many people write "waive off" but they usually mean "wave off."  "Waive" takes a direct object without a preposition, as in *they waive the requirement for some people.*  See [What does “waive off” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/39515/13287) at [English.SE].  (Also note [Is 'waived it through' correct English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/380570/13287)).

Answer (score 2):

Virgin Atlantic have to refund you the airport taxes.

And no, a Schengen short-stay visa is **not** enough to transit a UK airport without a visa. You will be denied Boarding in Amsterdam if you try.

The people who did transit successfully must have had a visa/residence permit of Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the US, or a Schengen long-stay visa or residence permit, or possibly the check-in staff missed the visa requirement (which they can be heavily fined for)